# XMLUnit's ElementQualifier gets confused when there are multiple Elements with same tag name

Tags: java, xml, dom, junit, xmlunit

I am trying to compare below two XMLs... I am doing a similarity test.

XML1

`<top>
    <first>true</first>         <!--- control node 1 ---->
    <second>                    <!--- control node 2 ---->
        <secondpart1>ooo</secondpart1>
    </second>
    <third>                     <!--- control node 3 ---->
        <thirdpart1>zzzz</thirdpar1>
    </third>
    <third>                     <!--- control node 4 ---->
        <thirdpart1>zzzz</thirdpar1>
        <thirdpart2>zzzz</thirdpar2>
    </third>
</top>`

XML2

`<top>
    <second>                    <!--- test node 1 ---->
        <secondpart1>ooo</secondpart1>
    </second>
    <third>                     <!--- test node 2 ---->
        <thirdpart1>zzzz</thirdpar1>
    </third>
    <third>                     <!--- test node 3 ---->
        <thirdpart1>zzzz</thirdpar1>
        <thirdpart2>zzzz</thirdpar2>
    </third>
    <first>true</first>         <!--- test node 4 ---->
</top>`

**I get this error**

[different] Expected number of child nodes '1' but was '2'. Looks like it compares control node 3 with test node 3. And since the names of the elements match "third", it does the comparision. Is there a work around this kind of situation ?

**This is my code**

```
    Diff d = new Diff(xmlResponseTrim, serializedResponseTrim);
    DetailedDiff dd = new DetailedDiff(d);
    dd.overrideDifferenceListener(new IgnoreTextAndAttributeValuesDifferenceListener());
    System.out.println(dd);
    assertTrue(dd.similar());
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ElementQualifier` interface is what determines which elements XMLUnit compares to each other.  For your specific case `RecursiveElementNameAndTextQualifier` would work, but it is not a general solution.  In more complex cases you will have to implement the matching strategy in an implementation of your own.